# How does a deadcat work?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life

This is a deadcat. It's a fluffy cover you put on top of a microphone to prevent wind noise on the recording. Lavalier and head-mounted microphones often use pieces of foam over the mic for the same reason. But *how*? I can't come up with any reasonable physics justification for why it would eliminate wind noise while leaving voices basically untouched.

[image: deadcat]

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Microphone_windscreens) Wikipedia article might help you:)

Answer (score 2):

Wind noise is generated when wind hits a surface. The rigid structure of the surface resonates at particular frequencies, generating the noise. A fluffy cover or foam has no resonant frequencies, so does not generate noise, and at the same time shields the microphone itself from the wind. Likewise the fluffy cover minimally impedes sound waves (vibration in the air).

Comment: Could it also be due to wind behaving as a sound wave with much lower frequency than a human voice?

Comment: @Poo2uhaha No. Wind is a flow, not a wave.